# a reference for a well-known theorem of analysis on convolution of a bounded and an $\ell$-integrable function is wanted

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, lebesgue-integral

On page 12 of Nummelin's *General Markov chains and Non-Negative Operators* some 'well-known theorem of analysis* is mentiones, "according to which the convolution of a bounded and of an $\ell$-integrable function  on $(\mathbb R, \mathscr R)$ is continuous". Can someone give a reference where I can find this theorem to check the rigorous statement? I doubt that a bounded function is always measurable and hence the product of a bounded and of an integrable function is neccesserely integrable...

Comment: I guess "$\ell$-integrable" means "Lebesgue integrable"? Does $\mathscr{R}$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets, or of Lebesgue-measurable sets?

Comment: I guess the measurability is a tacit assumption. For non-measurable functions, the convolution is generally not defined, as you suspect.